# Map an array to a complex type using Dozer

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, dozer

I am able to map array to complex type as specified in one of the answers in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016304/how-to-mapp-an-array-to-a-complex-type-using-dozer). However my application contains more than 500 classes and it will be very time consuming to identify and map these one by one. I am trying to build a generic method which would do this conversion. For example , complex type to array can be achieved by using the following methods. I am looking for ways to do the reverse operation -

```
public <T> T map(Object srcObj, Class<?> destClass, String mapId) {
    if (srcObj == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (srcObj.getClass().isArray()) {
        return (T) mapArrayToArray((Object[]) srcObj, destClass);
    }

    return (T) dozerBeanMapper.map(srcObj, destClass, mapId);
}

private Object mapArrayToArray(Object[] srcArray, Class<?> destClass) {
    Class<?> componentType = destClass.getComponentType();
    Object resultArray = Array.newInstance(componentType, srcArray.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++) {
        Object resultItem = this.map(srcArray[i], componentType);
        Array.set(resultArray, i, resultItem);
    }

    return resultArray;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how a "complex type" is mapped "to an array". The dozerBeanMapper.map maps some type X to another type Y. The remainder of this code does this for an array: map X[] to Y[]. The dozer mapper should be able to map Y to X, as it is bi-directions.